# How do I make my top bar contain all my divs in one line?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am building a website with a trustbox (trustpilot block) in the top bar. My trustbox gets pushed down under the top bar. I want everything to be in the same line with the trustbox positioned all the way to the right. How do I achieve this?

And by the way, how do I prevent the div that contains the trustbox, from cutting the trustbox as I experience this sometimes on smaller screens?

I've tried this:

```css
.header-top-bar-area {
    display: inline-block
    float: left
}
```

I've tried the above CSS content for the info section which is the location, email and phone section to the left.

```css
.trustbox {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And this for the trustbox, but it pushes the trustbox down.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="trustbox header-top-bar-area  col-xs-fit area-right" style=" white-space: normal; float: right; padding-top:5px;">
```

Comment: You shouldn't put link to your website in your question, because this link will become irrelevant in the question as soon as you fix your problem. Questions in SO are meant to perdure and be useful for future users and visitors. Try producing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably using snippets. Since this is a CSS question, you can complement it with screenshot of the current result, explaining why it is not what you want.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry I meant info. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]can you try adding css ***header-top-bar-area  col-xs-fit area-right*** in trustbox

```
<div class="trustbox header-top-bar-area  col-xs-fit area-right" style=" white-space: normal; float: right; padding-top:5px;">
```

this should work

Edit: I see it working, can you give me the screen resolutiuon you are working on.

Comment: Okay, this worked thank you. But the trustbox has been cut and now only shows two thirds. Do you know how to prevent it's parent div from getting smaller than the trustbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try rearranging your div like the below order and apply appropriate class to them..

[image: Working structure image]

Answer (score 0):

I think..  It wouldn't align because it's taking the < div> class or column..  It inherited from your structuring..  I.e your codes in your html
If you want it to float left..  You have to  adjust the column settings from your html  and also check your element properly, the opening and closing tag.
You will see that it follows one pattern that's why it can't change..
Also can't be 100% sure cause I haven't seen your full html codes and css arrangement .. Just try what I said and see if it works out.